# How $~2.576 \sqrt{{pq \over n}}\leq 0.02 ~$is derived from$~P(|\hat p-p|\leq 0.02)\geq 0.99 ,~P\left(|\hat p-p|<2.576\sqrt{{pq/n }}\right)=0.99$?

Tags: probability, inequality, systems-of-equations, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

We want to estimate the proportion of customers each of whom uses the particluar brand of detergent.

$$\begin{align}
\underbrace{p:=\text{population proportion which satisfies}~~0.8<p<0.9 }_{\text{known information} } 
\end{align}$$

And we want to determine the least number of samples for satisfying the following conditions.

$$\begin{align}
P(\left| \hat p-p \right| \leq 0.02  )\geq 0.99
~~\text{where}~~\hat p ~ ~\text{is a sample proportion}  \end{align}$$

The following is a mix of the official answer(Only quoted partially) and my thoughts for the solution.

We assume $~ n\gg1 ~$

$$\begin{align}
\hat p &= {x \over n }\\
    x&:=\text{number of customers who uses the detergent from}~n~\text{samples} \\
    X&\sim\mathcal B(n,p) 
\end{align}$$

Firstly, I can't understand why $~ p ~$ is used above instead of $~ \hat p ~$. Even I can't understand why binomial distribution can be applied to this random variable. Of course the $~ p,\hat p ~$represents a probability of randomly chosen person says that one uses a detergent of the brand, which can be handled as a boolean value hence intuitively the random variable can be  of a binomial distribution.

From the assumption $~ n\gg1 ~$ ,

$~ X\sim\mathcal N(np,np(1-p)) ~$ can be satisfied approximately. BTW I define $~ q:=1-p ~$

$$ Z:= {X-np \over \sqrt{npq}  } \sim\mathcal N(0,1) $$

$$  \underbrace{P(\left| Z \right|<2.576  )=0.99}_{\text{This can be derived using the table of std norm } }  $$

$$  \underbrace{P \left(\left| \hat p-p \right| <2.576 \sqrt{{pq \over n }} \right)}_{\text{This can be derived using the above 2 eqns.} }  =0.99 $$

The following is the main problem of this post.

$$ \underbrace{\color{fuchsia}{2.576 \sqrt{{pq \over n }}\leq 0.02  } }_{\text{How this can be derived?} }  $$

Definitely the following 2 eqns are the clinchers I presume.

$$\begin{align}
\underbrace{P(\left| \hat p-p \right| \leq 0.02  )\geq 0.99}_{\text{Constraint}}\\
 \underbrace{P \left(\left| \hat p-p \right| <2.576 \sqrt{{pq \over n }} \right) 
=0.99   }_{\text{Known holdable eqn} }  
\end{align}$$

Intuitively I think that the following inequality should be satisfied which sign is opposite of the pink inequality.

$$ {\color{green}{2.576 \sqrt{{pq \over n }}\geq 0.02  } } $$

Comment: I think that using proof of contradiction seems only a plausible way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F(\alpha) = P(|Z| \le \alpha)$.
Then $F(\alpha)$ is strictly increasing.

We have
$$P \left(\left| \hat p-p \right| \le 0.02 \right)
= P\left(\left|Z\right| \le 0.02\sqrt{\frac{n}{pq}} \right) \ge 0.99.$$

Since $P(|Z| < 2.576) = 0.99$, we have
$$0.02\sqrt{\frac{n}{pq}} \ge 2.576.$$